# DDX_Control example for mfc

Tags: mfc

I am not able to get the DDX_Control working example.

When I create the dialog box, I am not able to create a reference for the control object.

Google doesn't have examples as well.

Thanks.

```
void CEditDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBO1, m_cmbBox);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_Edit);
}

void CMFCApplicationDDEView::OnActionEdit2()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    CEditDialog dlg;
    CString str;
    dlg.m_cmbBox.GetLBText(0, str);

    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        MessageBox(dlg.cmbItemStr);
    }
}
```

dlg.m_cmbBox is NULL. Why is it null and how can I reference it in my view

Comment: which control you are using? If you are using `static` control then first rename its `ID`.

Comment: The dialog and control windows are created inside the DoModal call, so you cannot access them before DoModal. Those windows are destroyed before DoModal returns, so you cannot access them after DoModal. You can access data member variables of the CEditDialog class before and after DoModal. Put code to transfer between the data member variables and the controls inside your CEditDialog class, starting in OnInitDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for combo box and dialog box is correct but `m_cmbBox.GetLBText()` cannot be used before and after `DoModal()` because there is no window handle. Override like code below, then access `combo_str` instead of accessing windows

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEditDialog, CDialog)
    ON_COMMAND(IDOK, OnOK)
    //...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CEditDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    //Dialog is created, window handles are available, set text here
    return res;
}

void CEditDialog::OnOK()
{
    //get text before dialog's window handles are destroyed
    int sel = m_cmbBox.GetCurSel();
    if (sel >= 0) m_cmbBox.GetLBText(sel, cmbItemStr);
    CDialog::OnOK();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@barmak is correct in saying that you cannot access dialog box controls directly before the `InitDialog()` has executed.

However, you can set / retrieve the text of the edit portion of a combo box by using `DDX_CBString`, like:

```
// in .h file
CString m_cmbItemStr;

// in .cpp
void CEditDialog::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{   CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_CBString(pDX, IDC_COMBO1, m_cmbItemStr);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_Edit);
}

void CMFCApplicationDDEView::OnActionEdit2()
{   CEditDialog dlg;
    CString str = TEXT("some value");
    dlg.m_cmbItemStr = str;

    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
        MessageBox(dlg.m_cmbItemStr);
}
```